# _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, python-3.6

```
        sql = ("INSERT INTO {0} "
               "(id, timestamp, status, priority, client, group, capacity, level, mail_id) "
               "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)".format(TABLE_NAME_MAIL))
        values = ('NULL', report['timestamp'], 'succeeded', report['priority'], c.strip(), report['group'], 'NULL', 'NULL', ref_mailid)
        cursor.execute(sql, values)
        #cursor.execute('INSERT INTO %s VALUES (NULL,"%s","%s","%s","%s","%s",NULL,NULL,"%s") ' % (TABLE_NAME_REPORT, report['timestamp'], 'succeeded', report['priority'], c.strip(), report['group'], ref_mailid))
```

The commented out `cursor.execute` works, the uncommented throws an error:

> _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group, capacity, level, mail_id) VALUES ('NULL', '2014-12-05 23:46:56', 'succeed' at line 1")

Column '`id`' has `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`group` is a [reserved keyword in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html). Use backticks to escape the name

```
INSERT INTO {0} (id, timestamp, status, priority, client, `group`, capacity ...
                      here--------------------------------^-----^
```

or even better use a different column name.

And don't use `'NULL'` as parameter. Either use `NULL` without the quotes or remove it completely from the query:

```
INSERT INTO {0} (timestamp, ...
                ^----------no ID
```

Comment: Vielen Dank Jürgen, es hat geklappt! Actually, to add I use `None` instead of `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

When using an auto increment column, you have two options:

1. Insert a value in there (ie: Override the auto increment)
2. Do not set the column at all

1:

In case of setting a value, and you want to set "NULL" the column has to allow a NULL. This is rarely the case with an auto increment column since it would defeat its purpose.

So this is allowed:

```
INSERT INTO tab (id, sometext) VALUES (10,"Hi");
```

2:

Alternative (most used) is not to name the column at all:

```
INSERT INTO tab (sometext) VALUES ("Hi");
```

which would lead to mysql assigning a value to id in your table.